# Which preposition? -- "I'm going to hand in my work [ at / to / with ] my tutor."

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, verb-usage

I recently bumped into the verb **handing in**. When I wanted to use it in a sentence I couldn't tell whether I had to use it with **at/to/with** or anything else.

> I'm going to hand my work in [ at / to / with ] my tutor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, "to" is used to indicate a target or destination. "With" is used to indicate something acting or existing together. And "at" indicates a (current) location.

So if you are "handing in" your homework, presumably you are giving it to the teacher. The teacher is the person receiving it. So you "hand it in to the teacher".

If you and another student worked on the assignment together and then went together to give it to the teacher, you could say, "I handed in my work with my classmate".

If you were describing the location where you submitted it, you could say "I handed in my work at the teacher's home".

Comment: You're using teacher instead of tutor. Why exactly? (just curious)

Comment: @MatthijsvanHest In the U.S., at least (can't say for other English-speaking countries) we rarely refer to someone as a "tutor". We might say, "Mr Jones is my tutor" when we first mention him, but for the rest of the conversation we would call him "my teacher".

Comment: @Jay Don't we call tutors "tutor"? As a tutor (in the USA) who is definitely not a teacher, I've never been called a "teacher". They are not two different words for the same thing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Well, maybe I spoke too quickly. In my personal experience, tutors are routinely referred to as "teachers". The word "tutor" is used to describe someone, but is not normally used to address or refer to him except when necessary to avoid ambiguity. Like we might say "Smith is regional manager", but we wouldn't normally refer to him as "Regional Manager Smith" or say "I gave the file to my regional manager". But maybe I'm overstating it.

Comment: Maybe people like to call me "Tutor Todd" because of the alliteration. :-)

Comment: @todd If you teach about Henry VIII, you could be Tudor Tutor Todd.

Comment: Funny thing: I have a Henry VIII costume. Might have to add some math books and what-not to that for Halloween this year.

Answer (score 5):

It should be

> I am going to hand in my work **to** my tutor

Consider *'hand in'* in such context as *'submit'*.